# Java - Writing own HashMap - "put" method

Tags: java, junit, hashmap

I've been working on writing my own HashMap for some time now. All was going well until I came to a halt with writing the "put" method. I am not sure whether my rehash method is what is causing the test cases to fail, or if it is my actual put method. The test cases that I am using is from the JUnit library. The data structure that I am using to store the values for the map is an array of MyMapEntry objects (this implements the Entry class, I will provide the code for it). I have included all related code to this problem.

Entry class:

```
class MyMapEntry implements Entry<K,V>{

    private K key;
    private V value;

    public MyMapEntry(K k) {
        key = k;
    }

    public MyMapEntry(K k, V v) {
        this(k);
        value = v;
    }
    @Override
    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public V setValue(V v) {
        V oldValue = value;
        value = v;
        return oldValue;
    }

    public boolean equals(MyMapEntry bob) {
        return key.equals(bob.key);
    }

}
```

The put method:

```
@Override
public V put(K key, V value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < entryArray.length; i++) {
        MyMapEntry entryInArray = entryArray[i];
        if (entryInArray != null) {
            if (entryInArray.getKey().hashCode() == entry.getKey().hashCode()) {
                entryInArray.setValue(value);
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
    if (entryArray[index] != null) { // Rehash if there is a collision
        rehash();
        index = entry.hashCode() % size;
    }
    entryArray[index] = entry;
    actualSize++;
    return value;
}
```

Here is the rehash algorithm that I have written. I am not entirely sure that it is written correctly:

```
private void rehash() {
    entryArray = Arrays.copyOf(entryArray, entryArray.length * 2);
    MyMapEntry[] tempArray = Arrays.copyOf(entryArray, entryArray.length);
    Arrays.fill(entryArray, null);
    for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
        MyMapEntry entry = tempArray[i];
        if (entry != null) {
            int index = entry.hashCode() % tempArray.length;
            entryArray[index] = entry;
        }
    }
    size = entryArray.length;
}
```

This is the test method that actually builds the data structure that I created:

```
public HashMapAPlus<MyDumbyData, String> buildReHashHashMap(int l){
    HashMapAPlus<MyDumbyData, String> bob = new HashMapAPlus<>(l);
    MyDumbyData d = new MyDumbyData("Bobby", Color.red);
    bob.put(d,  "Love ya");
    d = new MyDumbyData("Ralph", Color.blue);
    bob.put(d,  "Snake");
    d = new MyDumbyData("Blake", Color.black);
    bob.put(d,  "Something");
    d = new MyDumbyData("Roman", Color.white);
    bob.put(d,  "Something else");
    d = new MyDumbyData("Sam", Color.magenta);
    bob.put(d,  "Nothing much");
    d = new MyDumbyData("Victor", Color.cyan);
    bob.put(d,  "Something more");
    d = new MyDumbyData("Nick", Color.yellow);
    bob.put(d,  "Don't know");
    d = new MyDumbyData("Frank", Color.orange);
    bob.put(d,  "Not sure");
    d = new MyDumbyData("Aaron", Color.green);
    bob.put(d,  "Not at all");
    d = new MyDumbyData("Brit", Color.red);
    bob.put(d,  "Not sure what");
    return bob;
}
```

The "MyDumbyData" is supposed to represent each key in the hashmap for each test case. This is the class code:

```
public class MyDumbyData {
    private String name;
    private Color color;

    public MyDumbyData(String n, Color c) {
        name = n;
        color = c;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public boolean equals(MyDumbyData dd) {
        return name.equals(dd.getName()) && color.equals(dd.getColor());
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode() + color.hashCode();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name+": "+color.toString();
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the test case that is failing:

```
@Test
public void testAddGet1() {
    HashMapAPlus<MyDumbyData, String> bob = this.buildReHashHashMap(10);
    assertEquals(10, bob.size());
    MyDumbyData d = new MyDumbyData("Bobby", Color.red);
    assertEquals("Love ya", bob.get(d));          // This is where the first assertion error is.
    d = new MyDumbyData("Ralph", Color.blue);
    assertEquals("Snake", bob.get(d));
    d = new MyDumbyData("Blake", Color.black);
    assertEquals("Something", bob.get(d));
    d = new MyDumbyData("Roman", Color.white);
    assertEquals("Something else", bob.get(d));
    d = new MyDumbyData("Sam", Color.magenta);
    assertEquals("Nothing much", bob.get(d));
    d = new MyDumbyData("Victor", Color.cyan);
    assertEquals("Something more", bob.get(d));
    assertNull(bob.getLinkedListArray());
    assertNotNull(bob.getMapEntryArray());
}
```

Note that if the line where the first assertion error occurs is commented out, the test case passes.

I apologize if I have provided too much code. It is just that all of this code is being used for the final result.

All help is appreciated
- Bob

Comment: So why not just use a debugger to see what's going wrong? Also, iterating over the underlying array for every operation completely defeats the point of a hashmap.

Comment: And, solely relying on the hash code of the key to determine equality is insufficient. Especially since your `hashCode()` implementation is fishy.

Comment: Variables `entry` and `index` didn't declared in scope of `put` method so unclear they initial values

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are a lot of errors you need to take a look at:

1. The nature of hashcodes is that you can't assume you won't get a collision even after rehashing. Two unequal objects are allowed to return the same hashcode.
2. Your `put` implementation is iterating through all the map entry. The whole point of using hashes is to use them to index into the array.
3. There's nothing stopping an implementation of hashcode returning negative values. Your use of % is not guaranteed to return a positive value.

There are actually many other issues I can see. But I suggest you take a different approach to building and debugging your code. You are falling into the trap of writing all the code then building a single complex test case that tests everything. Instead:

- Start with very simple test cases (e.g. getting null values for non-existent keys, putting a getting a value, overwriting a value)
- Once those are working build to more complex cases (clashing hashcodes, rehashing etc.).
- Make sure each test tests one thing.
- Make sure each test sets up its own data
- Get the simple things working before worrying about the complex use cases.
- Run the full set of tests each time you make a change.